# Solve $x^2y''+xy'+y=0$ using the power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Basically I have to find the power series of the ODE above.

What I have so far:

$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_nx^n$

$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }na_nx^{n-1}$

$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }(n-1)(n)a_nx^{n-2}$

therefore,

$xy'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }na_nx^{n}$

$x^2y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }(n-1)(n)a_nx^{n}$

since the counters of the summations are different, I evaluate $y$ at $n=0,1$ and $xy'$ at $n=1$

I then get,

($\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }(n-1)(n)a_nx^{n} )+(a_1x^1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty }na_nx^{n})+(a_0x^0+a_1x^1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }a_nx^n)=0$

This then leaves me with

$a_0=0$

$2a_1=0; a_1 = 0$

$(n-1)(n)a_n+na_n+a_n=0$

I then get a recursion formula of:

$a_n(n^2+1)=0$

which would make my $a_n$ equal to zero.

Where am I wrong? Symbolab says that the answer to this ODE is

$y=c_1\cos(\ln(x))+c_2\sin(\ln(x))$

Comment: Hint: show $x^z$ is an eigenfunction of $x^2D^2+xD+I$ for each $z\in\Bbb C$.

Comment: I am not sure, but probably at the $2a_1=0$ step, $a_0=0$ is fine as the whole equation should satisfy at $x=0$, but after that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n(n^2+1) = 0$ doesn't probably mean $a_1=0$

Comment: Thinking about this, I think the specific problem is that you assume $y$ has an expansion as a power series around $0$. The solution symbolab gives is not defined at $x=0$ (and it also doesn't have a limit in general) so it doesn't have a power series around zero. Therefore the method you use can't give you all solutions.

Comment: @EnEm As far as I can tell that is fine as we can simply look at the $n$th derivate at zero of the power series. This must be identically zero, so we conclude that all coefficients are zero.

Comment: If that is the correct general solution then the only solution regular at 0 (which is all that can be found using your method) is identically zero. Adding negative powers does not help because the singularity is not of that type. An alternate way to go would be to expand around a different point ($1$ seems convenient). Another alternative is to anticipate the dependence on the logarithm and thus change variables. As yet another alternative you can just identify the eigenfunction structure mentioned in J.G.'s comment and then pick the choice with the right eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Your working is entirely correct – but the nontrivial solution is not a power series around $0$. To derive the nontrivial solution change variables $w=\ln x$; the equation becomes, with differentiating now in $w$,
$$x^2(y''/x^2-y'/x^2)+x(y'/x)+y=y''+y=0$$
Of course this has basis solutions $y=\sin w$ and $y=\cos w$, so the general solution is $A\cos\ln x+B\sin\ln x$.

Comment: How were you able to obtain $x^2(y''/x^2 - y'/x^2)+x(y'/x)+y=0$?

Comment: @mEXsACHINE It's [Faà di Bruno's fomula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), detailing what to do when changing higher-order derivatives to a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You got $$a_0+2a_1x+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty (n^2+1)a_nx^n= 0$$
And you are looking for a suitable sequence $(a_n)$ which verify this, clearly the zero function is a solution to this ODE, but you are looking for non-zero solutions. Hence we must look for $(a_n)$ where at least one term is non zero.

You have $a_0= y(0)$ and $a_1= y'(0)$ could be your initial conditions, that are necessary to give a unique solution to your problem (why? Look up Cauchy's theorem). Now let us look for a suitable sequence $(a_n)$ where we know that $a_0, a_1$ are given. We want $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n^2+1)a_nx^n= -2a_1x -a_0 $ which, for non-zero $x$, is equivalent to

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((n+2)^2+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}= \sum_{n=2}^\infty (n^2+1)a_nx^{n-2}= -\frac{2a_1}{x} -\frac{a_0}{x^2}$   , but we know the power series of the $\frac{1}{x}$ function :
$$\frac{-2a_1}{x}= -2a_1\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}= -2a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^n= -2a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}x^k$$
And the other term is:
$$\frac{-a_0}{x^2}= a_0(\frac{1}{x})'= a_0 \sum_{n=1}^\infty -n(1-x)^{n-1}= -na_0 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}x^k$$
($\textbf{above there is a mistake in differentiating the power series !}$)

Adding both gives the condition:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((n+2)^2+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}= (-2a_1-na_0) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}x^k$$
You need to work on the triangular sum in the right to have a sum over $k$ :
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}x^k= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n= k}^\infty (-1)^k{n\choose k}x^k$$
Hoping that the dummy indices won't confuse you and you can immediately conclude that
$$ ((n+2)^2+1)a_{n+2}= (-2a_1-na_0) \sum_{k=n}^\infty (-1)^n{k\choose n}$$
Or $$a_{n+2}= \frac{(-2a_1-na_0)}{((n+2)^2+1)} \sum_{k=n}^\infty (-1)^n{k\choose n}$$
Which is well a recursion relation to compute all of the $a_n$'s 
($\textbf{If we can make sense of such summation ! Which we haven't done here}$)

You can simplify it to $$a_{n}= \frac{-2a_1-na_0}{n^2+1} \sum_{k=n-2}^\infty (-1)^n{k\choose n-2}\ , \ \text{ for all } n\geq2 $$

Please do not worry about Symbolab expression, as I think this is enough as an answer if you are doing it for an exam or a homework, it depends actually on how much knowledge have you covered in relation to power series. But you can take it as a good exercise to check why this expression verifies the same recursion relation.

Comment: Unless I am missing something the series you use doesn't converge as it's terms do not tend to zero. That means this answer cannot be used as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I used the development of $\frac{1}{x}$ which is only valid when $x\in (-1,1)$

Comment: I'm talking about the series in your final definition of $a_n$. That series has non-zero integer terms so it clearly doesn't converge so you haven't defined $a_n$, how you got the expression doesn't matter.

Comment: $a_n\sim \frac{(-1)^n}{n}b_n$ where $b_n=\sum_k \frac{k!}{(n-2)!(k-n+2)!}$ and the claim is that the power series converges for $x\in (-1,1)\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: Have you actually tried computing $a_n$, or even approximating it, say $a_2$ when $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$? Alternatively can you actually prove that $a_n$ is well defined rather than just claiming it? I just can't see how your answer is supposed to make sense.

Comment: Having now read you derivation there is another problem. In the line following 'And the other term is:' you move $n$ outside of the summation which binds it. This is invalid, so your derivation is false here. Finally you fail to reduce the factor in front of $a_0$ in the final expression by $2$.

Comment: yes thank you for pointing out that. My answer is useless unless we can make sense of such 'summation'

Comment: No problem. Also sorry if I sounded harsh.

Comment: What do you mean by $n$ outside which binds it? This derivation is not done correctly anyway, we should differentiate inside the $k$ sum

Comment: I can correct it but as long as we don't define a general 'summation' this won't work, but I do think it will work if you think of general summation like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n= \frac{-1}{12}$

Comment: That is essentially what I am refering to.  I assumed the derivation was done inside and then the $n$ was brought outside the sum. What I mean by 'binding' is that the summation is running over $n$ so $n$ only makes sense as a variable inside the summation, otherwise we can't determine whether the inner or outer $n$ is being used.

Comment: Yes that $n$ should stay inside

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular singular ODE (or simply an Euler-Cauchy DE), the power series to use is a Frobenius power series $$y(x)=\sum a_nx^{r+n}.$$

Computing derivatives as you did results in
$$
\forall n\in\Bbb N~:~((n+r)^2+1)a_n=0.
$$
As especially $a_0\ne 0$, because by construction $x^r$ is the smallest power that actually occurs in the series, you get $$r^2=-1,~~ r=\pm i.$$ The useful expressions for the solution basis functions $x^r=e^{r\ln(x)}$ are $$e^{\pm i\ln x}$$ or their linear combinations $$\sin(\ln x), ~~\cos(\ln x).$$

Comment: this is a good solution for when $x>0$, it is worth mentioning that this problem can have different solutions depending on initial conditions and range of $x$

Comment: This is usually the domain when nothing else is indicated. As the equation is singular in its order in $x=0$, the domain for an ODE can only be $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$. One could write the basis solutions as $\sin(\ln(x/x_0))$ etc. which is valid for both intervals, as $x_0$ has to be inside the current domain.

Comment: How did you get $e^{±ilnx}$ from $((n+r)^2+1)a_n=0$? Sorry I'm just confused.

Comment: The factor $x^r$ can be written as $e^{r·\ln(x)}$, especially if $r$ like in $r=\pm i$ is not real.

Comment: Thank you! But how does $e^{±ilnx}$ turn into $y=c_1\cos(\ln(x))+c_2\sin(\ln(x))$ ? I know that $e^{ix}=cosx+isinx$ but how do you remove the $i$ coefficient in $sinx$?

Comment: You take suitable linear combinations of both exponentials. Or consider that $Re(c·e^{i\ln x})$ is a real function for any complex $c$.